# Why doesn't this html5 track tag work?

Tags: html, html5-video

This is the code:

```
<video controls="" src="Arrested%20Development.S04E11.A%20New%20Attitude.mkv">
    <track kind="subtitles" label="English subtitles" src="Subs\Arrested Development.S04E11.A New Attitude-eng.vtt" srclang="en" default="">
    </track>
</video>
```

I can see the video fine, but not the subtitles (not even the subtitles button on the controls).

(On Chrome)

Comment: In which browser are you checking? <track> only working in IE10, Opera and Chrome. Firefox and safari doesn't support it

Comment: which browser do you use?

Comment: I also have the same problem. Thanks for posting this question! By the way, is the subtitle file in the correct format? Can you please share a part of that file?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use the control parameter in the video tag and default parameter in track tag but not sure if they will solve the problem. I also use playr: https://github.com/delphiki/Playr which makes my life a little easier!

Comment: Tried it, not effect (except removing the controls altogether). Thanks for the extension suggestion but I'd rather use clean html5 code.

Comment: Sorry couldn't help. I will post if I can get it to work. Good luck!